# Couldn't import google's Status proto in my proto file

Tags: maven, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm trying to import "google/rpc/status.proto" proto using maven.

I'm using Intellij to create protos and I've all the protos in a project, let's call it as protos and I've a module name foo in the project with its own pom.xml file. Below is the structure.

```
protos
----> foo
--------> proto
------------> foo.proto
```

I'm trying to import "google/rpc/status.proto" in foo.proto

In foo.proto I'm trying to do this:

```
syntax = "proto2";

package foo.proto;

import "google/rpc/status.proto";


message SomeResponse {
  optional google.rpc.Status status = 1;
}

...
...
```

In pom.xml I've the below build with plugins:

```
<build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${os-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${protobuf-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protoc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                    </protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${io.grpc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                    </pluginArtifact>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}</outputDirectory>
                    <clearOutputDirectory>false</clearOutputDirectory>
                    <protoSourceRoot>proto</protoSourceRoot>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile-custom</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I've below dependencies

```
...

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-google-common-protos</artifactId>
    <version>2.16.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Protoc command that I'm trying:

```
protoc --java_out=./foo --proto_path=./foo/proto ./foo/proto/foo.proto
```

I'm getting as

```
google/rpc/status.proto: File not found.
foo.proto:5:1: Import "google/rpc/status.proto" was not found or had errors.
```

Please help me with the above error. Also I am not sure if using maven is the right build tool for protobufs. Should I consider using Bazel for Protobuf, will it solve problems, please let me know.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with building protobufs w/ Java|Maven. However, you will need to have a local copy of [`google/api/status.proto`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/rpc/status.proto) and this file takes a further dependency on Google's Well-Known Type `google/protobuf/any.proto` (which should be available w/ `protoc`).

Comment: Once you have a local copy of `status.proto` (you need only that single file but it should be placed in a folder structure that preserves the `package` i.e. `google/rpc/status.proto` (so I recommend e.g. `googleapis/google/rpc/status.proto`), you will need to add another `--proto_path=./googleapis/google/rpc` so that `protoc` can find it to generate the Java stubs

Comment: Apologies, `--proto_path=./googleapis` (just the to the root of that folder)

Comment: Why are you running `protoc` manually instead of using the maven plugin that you've already configured? What happens when you use `mvn compile`?

Comment: @EricAnderson I tried `mvn compile`. It works fine and the build is success but Intellij shows error. `protoc` detects the error when ran but `mvn compile` doesn't. I'm not sure why. Any help on what's happening?

Comment: It seems removing outputDirectory is worth a try to improve the IDE integration. https://github.com/xolstice/protobuf-maven-plugin/issues/63#issuecomment-506996388